# JS. How do I replace text in the html () object within a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JS I copied html code into variable.

```
html_block = $(".first-prj-container").html();
```

In some places it is necessary to make a replacement for the text. This can be either plain text or class names, IDs. Is it possible to make replacement via strReplace, and then append the result into the page like this:

```
$("#all-prj-container").append(html_block);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let htmlToReplace = $(".first-prj-container").prop('outerHTML')
let updatedHtml = htmlToReplace.replace('hi', 'hello')

$("#all-prj-container").append(updatedHtml);
```

See more here [outerHTML - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use regEx to refine your filter for white spaces, case sensitivity, or filter for certain nested tags:

```
let updatedHtml= $(".first-prj-container")
    .innerHTML.toLowerCase() //make case-insensitive, can also be done with regEx "i"
    .replace(/\s/g,'') //remove white spaces
    .replace("(hi)(?!(.(?!<h1))*?</h1>)", "hello"); //skip h1 tag content
$(".first-prj-container").innerHTML = updatedHtml;
```